# How do you add a Column with a Case as the default in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
ALTER TABLE [table_name] ADD COLUMN alloc_strat varchar(25) NOT NULL 
 DEFAULT(CASE
    WHEN (shelf_life_unit = 'Months') THEN 'Min Remaining Shelf Life'
    ELSE 'FIFO')
;
```

This isn't working, Is there a way to do this in one sql statement

Comment: I think what you need is a trigger

Comment: BTW: *This isn't working,* is not an error description. Please explain what is not working. Any error message, wron result?

Comment: Execution finished with errors.
Result: near ")": syntax error
At line 1:
ALTER TABLE up_hglistaz ADD COLUMN alloc_strat varchar(25) NOT NULL 
 DEFAULT(CASE
 WHEN (shelf_life_unit = 'Months') THEN 'Min Remaining Shelf Life'
 ELSE 'FIFO')

Comment: Jenga Answered my question. It isn't possible, I will have to look into triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite the added columns are not allowed to have expressions are their default.

> The following illustrates the syntax of ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN
> statement:
>
> ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN column_definition; Code language:
> SQL (Structured Query Language) (sql) There are some restrictions on
> the new column:
>
> The new column cannot have a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint. If the
> new column has a NOT NULL constraint, you must specify a default value
> for the column other than a NULL value. The new column cannot have a
> default of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_DATE, and CURRENT_TIME, **or an
> expression**. If the new column is a foreign key and the foreign key
> constraint check is enabled, the new column must accept a default
> value NULL.

[Source](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-alter-table/)